# What is ASP.NET vNext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Can anybody tell me what is ASP.NET vNext?
Every new version on .Net is something like .NET 1.0, .NET 2.0, .NET 3.0, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0 then why this version is not something like ASP.NET 6.0?

Comment: This is for ASP.NET MVC. MVC versions 3,4,5 and this is the version 6. [Learn about what's coming next with ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext)

Comment: Generally a new yet-to-be-released version is popularly called v.Next or vNext. Not necessarily ASP.Net.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

vNext is just the name given to product in the pre-release mode, like c# vNext which will apparently be released as  C# 6.0, maybe ASP.NET vNext will have a numbering when it releases.

> What is ASP.NET vNext?

Microsoft ASP.NET vNext is a smaller and efficient framework as a result of rebuilding the libraries from ground up.

**What's new in vNext**

- Cloud-optimized versions of MVC, Web API, Web Pages, SignalR, and Entity Framework.
- MVC, Web API, and Web Pages will be merged into one framework, called MVC 6.
- MVC 6 has no dependency on System.Web. The result is a leaner framework, with faster startup time and lower memory consumption.
- vNext is host agnostic. You can host your app in IIS, or self-host in a custom process.
- Dependency injection is built into the framework. Use your preferred IoC container to register dependencies.
- vNext uses the [Roslyn](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/) compiler to compile code dynamically. You will be able to edit a code file, refresh the browser, and see the changes without rebuilding the project.
- vNext is open source and cross platform.

**More information:**

- [Overview on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/overview)
- [Getting started with ASP.NET vNext](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/)
- [Blogpost by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETVNext.aspx)
- [Blogpost by David Fowler](http://davidfowl.com/asp-net-vnext/)
- [Contributing to ASP.NET vNext](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)
- [Sample ASP.NET vNext applications](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext)

Comment: damn microsoft just call it n.V. or NV or nV or n.v. or nv, for next version.

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET vNext is the next version of ASP.NET, but it hasn't shipped yet, so it is not an official version. "vNext" is just a working title.

Comment: When its scheduled to be released?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET vNext was the code-name for the next generation of ASP.NET, whose official name is ASP.NET 5. As of now ASP.NET 5 is not yet finished and documentation about can be found at http://asp.net/vnext.

ASP.NET 5 is not just an evolution of the previous version(s), it is rebuilt from the ground. Existing ASP.NET applications will run on ASP.NET 5 without modifications, but to take advantage of the new features, such applications will have to be ported to the new version.

Here's a little excerpt of what http://asp.net has to say about ASP.NET 5:

---

ASP.NET 5 is a lean .NET stack for building modern web apps. We built it from the ground up to provide an optimized development framework for apps that are either deployed to the cloud or run on-premises. It consists of modular components with minimal overhead, so you retain flexibility while constructing your solutions.

ASP.NET 5 includes the following features:

- New flexible and cross-platform runtime
- New modular HTTP request pipeline
- Cloud-ready environment configuration
- Unified programming model that combines MVC, Web API, and Web Pages
- Ability to see changes without re-building the project
- Side-by-side versioning of the .NET Framework
- Ability to self-host or host on IIS
- New tools in Visual Studio 2015
- Open source in GitHub

The changes we made for ASP.NET 5 were based on customer requests and feedback. These changes simplify development, hosting, and maintenance, and are targeted to modern web apps.

Your legacy apps will run on the new version of the ASP.NET without any modifications. However, to take advantage of the new features in ASP.NET 5, you will need to port your existing code to the new framework. You will find many similarities between ASP.NET 5 and earlier versions of ASP.NET, so porting code involves fixing particular issues rather than re-writing the app.